# Docker in google idx ide

Tags: docker, ide, cloud, port, idx

I have enabled docker inside google idx ide and composed the docker file and every went well but the ports are not showing and its showing trying to hard restart error
Please help

I tried to have my port opened but it didn't opened and showed some error